# Mbient Lab Sensor API C++ Help: Undeclared Identifier for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, build, linker, sensors

I recently purchased an Mbient Lab IMU Bluetooth Sensor, and I am attempting to work through the API, following the tutorial [found here.](https://mbientlab.com/cppdocs/latest/mblmwmetawearboard.html)

I built the project using CMAKE in Visual Studio 2019. I created a solution file and I am struggling to begin writing code for the project. I created a solution, included the directory found in the src folder, linked the folder including the Win32 library and added it into additional dependencies in the input section in the linker. However, while following the simple tutorial seen in the first section of the code, I am receiving an error of the write_gatt_char, read_gatt_char, and enable_char_notify functions being an undeclared identifier, and I cannot find a fix.

One major difference is that the connection.h file is not present. Instead, the file with those functions is in the btle_connection.h header file in a separate folder.

The code is seen below:

```
#include "metawear/core/metawearboard.h"
#include "metawear/platform/btle_connection.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    MblMwBtleConnection btle_conn = {nullptr, write_gatt_char, read_gatt_char, enable_char_notify};
    MblMwMetaWearBoard* board = mbl_mw_metawearboard_create(&btle_conn);
}
```

And I receive a C2065 error that those functions are undeclared identifiers.

Furthermore, in the btle_connectoin header file, these functions are defined in the structure seen below:

```
/**
 * Wrapper class containing functions for communicating with the MetaWear through a Bluetooth Low Energy connection.
 */
typedef struct {
    /**
     * Provides the calling function the ability to pass any context specific data required
     */
    void *context;
    /** 
     * Writes the characteristic and value to the device
     * @param context           Pointer to the <code>context</code> field
     * @param caller            Object using this function pointer
     * @param characteristic    Gatt characteristic to write
     * @param value             Value to write as a byte array
     * @param length            Length of the byte array
     */
    void (*write_gatt_char)(void *context, const void* caller, MblMwGattCharWriteType writeType, const MblMwGattChar* characteristic, 
            const uint8_t* value, uint8_t length);
    /**
     * Reads the value of the characteristic from the device
     * @param context               Pointer to the <code>context</code> field
     * @param caller                Object using this function pointer
     * @param characteristic        Gatt characteristic to read
     * @param handler               Callback function to handle the received value
     */
    void (*read_gatt_char)(void *context, const void* caller, const MblMwGattChar* characteristic, MblMwFnIntVoidPtrArray handler);
    /**
     * Enables notifications for characeristic changes
     * @param context               Pointer to the <code>context</code> field
     * @param caller                Object using this function pointer
     * @param characteristic        Characteristic to enable notifications for
     * @param handler               Callback function for handling characteristic notifications
     * @param ready                 Callback function to handle when the enable notify task is completed
     */
    void (*enable_notifications)(void *context, const void* caller, const MblMwGattChar* characteristic, MblMwFnIntVoidPtrArray handler, MblMwFnVoidVoidPtrInt ready);
    /**
     * Register a handler for disconnect events
     * @param context               Pointer to the <code>context</code> field
     * @param caller                Object using this function pointer
     * @param handler               Handler to respond to the disconnect event
     */
    void (*on_disconnect)(void *context, const void* caller, MblMwFnVoidVoidPtrInt handler);
} MblMwBtleConnection;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Is it possible that I am linking/built it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Although the functions are declared in the `btle_connection` header file, as you've pointed out, they aren't defined. We have to write our own definitions/implementations of these functions before calling `mbl_mw_metawearboard_create`.

[btle documentation](https://mbientlab.com/cppdocs/latest/btlecommunication.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)